# Speculative execution and malloc

Tags: c++, speculative-execution

After reading about Spectre & Meltdown vulnerabilities, I learned about speculative execution.

Given the following simple C++ program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void mallocBranch(int i) {
   if (i < 500) {
      malloc(i);
   }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
   for (i := 0; i < 5000; i++) {
      mallocBranch(1);
   }
   mallocBranch(500000000);

   return 0;
}
```

- I am assuming that the `malloc` calls are not optimized out by the compiler.

Q: What happens when `mallocBranch(500000000)` is called? Will the CPU look at the branch-prediction cache and see that past calls to `if (i < 500)` succeeded and speculatively execute the branch with `malloc(500000000)`? Would the number of branches in `malloc` overwrite the entire contents of the branch-prediction cache each time? If `malloc(500000000)` is actually speculatively executed, would 500million bytes of memory be allocated to the process, if only temporarily?

Comment: You have completely misunderstood how this works. Branch prediction doesn't mean that evaluation of `if` will not happen. CPU is able to execute instruction out of order (as listed in memory) as long as it can prove that instruction do not depend on results of other. If branch prediction fails all predictions are doped and everything is evaluated again from scratch.

Comment: as this is all in a single translation unit the compiler knows all that is needed to know that `mallocBranch(500000000);` is a noop. The resulting program has no branch on that call ("I am assuming that the malloc calls are not optimized out by the compiler." does not change that, because there was no call to `malloc` in the first place on that call)

Comment: *Assuming* that the branch predictor is simple enough to be fooled by this, `malloc()` won't allocate *anyway*, because you probably don't have the memory `mmap()` ed yet. So even *if* speculative execution runs ahead far enough to find out that fulfilling the allocation request requires `mmap()`, that's a syscall, which will have speculative execution mitigations. Even if it doesn't, `mmap()` will need to modify MMU state, which will require I/O and memory barriers, limiting speculative execution again.